Rewriting URLs using .htaccess in cloudflare pages (can it be done with headers?)
edit: Maybe htaccess does not work on cloudflare pages in the first place. I know cloudflare pages has redirects (changes the URL for the client) and headers
Can it be done with headers? (if htaccess really does not work)
Requirement
I am trying to rewrite this URL
https://expensetracker.rweb.site/expenses/2024/August (client side URL)
to
https://expensetracker.rweb.site/expenses?year=2024&month=August (real URL that javascript can use to access parameters)
expenses.html is the file here but by default cloudflare removes the extension in the URL
The month and year are just examples, i need it for things that will make more sense
I dont know php, but if need be i can use it too if thats the only way for this to work

Details
I have tried multiple ways to do this in .htaccess but none of them seem to be working and only redirecting me to index.html instead
Some were generated by https://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/
The ones which i tried and made sense to me:
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /expenses?sheet=$1 [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^expenses/(.*)$ expenses?q=$1 [L,NC]


What i am using
I am using free cloudflare pages with a free subdomain (rweb.site) to host the website
So i can not use page rules since it requires the actual domain (not my subdomain)
Most importantly, does .htaccess even work with cloudflare pages (I could only find mixed answers on this)
